# password expire date removing for linux

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, unix-socket

i have below commands am using it for removing expire date for my user at unix it's working but for linux it's not working below example is for unix if anyone have a linux command like this i'll be thankful

```
root@servername>passwd -s user
user    PS    05/13/15          84
root@servername>passwd -x -1 user
passwd: password information changed for user
```

**before**

```
username:$md5$Dtj/7tJf$$VY7qJE2us6ODX/2xLUGAS:16568::84::::
```

**after**

```
username:$md5$Dtj/7tJf$$VY7qJE2us6ODX/2xLUGAS:16548::::::
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the `usermod` command:

```
usermod -e -1 $USER
```

Where `-1` serves as the argument to `-e`.

To remove the expire date.

The expiration date parameter can be empty. (but not missing when the `-e` option is used) The `-e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE` option is described as follows in `man 8 usermod`:

> An empty EXPIRE_DATE argument will disable the expiration of the
> account.

The issue being on how you interpret `"empty"`. Both forms, `-e` or `--expiredate=` will accept an empty argument. Those being:

```
  -e ''
```

or

```
  --expiredate=
```

With thanks to [@alx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6872717/alx)

Comment: You can also use `chage` command but I think `usermod` will be more portable

Comment: You can actually pass an empty argument to the `-e` option: a) `usermod -e '' $USER;` or b) `usermod --expiredate= $USER;`.

Comment: @alx - well played. Answer updated to reflect the forms of `empty` arguments accepted.

Answer (score 3):

chage -I -1 -m 0 -M 99999 -E -1 username